# Extract local hour from timestamp with time zone

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm trying to extract the local hour from a `timestamp with time zone`, but as I am new to working with this data type, I get unexpected results.

I was expecting `22` as output for every row below.

```
with my_data as(
   select to_timestamp_tz(ts, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss tzh:tzm') as tsz
     from (select '2017-12-07 22:23:24 +' || lpad(level, 2, '0') || ':00' as ts  
             from dual connect by level <= 10
          )       
)
select dbtimezone
      ,sessiontimezone
      ,tsz
      ,extract(hour from tsz)
  from my_data;
```

[image]

Why does this happen, and what do I need to do to extract the local hour from a timestamp with time zone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [documentation of EXTRACT(datetime)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions067.htm#SQLRF00639):

> When extracting from a datetime with a time zone value, the value returned is in UTC.

Use `TO_CHAR(tsz, 'HH24')` or `EXTRACT(hour from cast(tsz as timestamp))` if you like to get local hours.

Comment: It's amazing how many hoops one has to go through working with timezone-related temporals in databases. I wish they streamlined all of this some day.